# Multiple relationships in a query

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I’m researching a bit WP_Query and me a problem has arisen.

I have custom fields in tickets and would like to make a WP_Query showing this (put an example):

```
(field1 = “data1″ AND field2 = “data2″) OR (field1 = “data2″ AND field2 = “data1″)
```

To do this I created this query but it returns me well.

```
'meta_query' => array (
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array (
        'key'     => 'field1',
        'value'   => 'data1',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array (
        'key'     => 'field2',
        'value'   => 'data2',
        'compare' => '='
    ),

    'relation' => 'OR',
    array (
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
            array (
                'key'     => 'field1',
                'value'   => 'data2',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array (
                'key'     => 'field2',
                'value'   => 'data1',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Does anyone know what I'm wrong? I tried different ways but nothing (I put this because it is what I think is the one that comes closest.

Greetings and thanks!

PD: Sorry for my english! (Google Translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, meta queries do not support a combination of `AND` & `OR`. But what you *can* do, is make two queries, one for each rule, then combine the results.

```
$group_1 = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'meta_query'     => array (
            array (
                'key'   => 'field1',
                'value' => 'data1',
            ),
            array (
                'key'   => 'field2',
                'value' => 'data2',
            ),
        ),
    )
);

$group_2 = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'meta_query'     => array (
            array (
                'key'   => 'field1',
                'value' => 'data2',
            ),
            array (
                'key'   => 'field2',
                'value' => 'data1',
            ),
        ),
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post__in' => array_merge( $group_1, $group_2 ),
    )
);
```

Comment: According the to documentation, meta_query does support relation.

Comment: @EricHolmes It does indeed, but as I said, not both at once.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `posts_clauses` filter for that. Just alter the array parts in there to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could still do this within a WP_Query delcaration. Use the `compare` value of `IN` and pass the value an array of possible values.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'field1',
            'value' => array('data1', data2'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field2',
            'value' => array('data1', data2'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    ) );
```

This would also however, return the possibilities of `(field1='data1' and field1='data1') or (field1='data2' and field1='data2)'`, so perhaps this isn't ideal. I'm not sure if that doesn't meet your requirements.